# Image of the week "hall of fame"

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that [Photo SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of 2022 in reverse chronological order.

**Hall of Fame Archives**:
[2021](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7207),
[2020](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7103),
[2019](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7102),
[2018](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5829),
[2017](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5603),
[2016](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5317),
[2015](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043),
[2014](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659),
[2013](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230),
[2012](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741),
[2011](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740),
[2010](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)

---

## Hall of Fame

#### [13 June 2022: Famous Buildings](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128984/)

**The Eiffel Tower** – [srini](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/37085/)

[image: The Eiffel Tower]

Nikon D40, 30mm, ƒ/4.2, 1/3200, ISO200

---

#### [6 June 2022: Famous Buildings](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128980/)

**Three Architectures** – [Kevin Rubin](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/11891/)

[image: Three Architectures]

Some years ago I saw a theme on some social medium to try photographing three different types of architecture in the same photo, so I thought I'd try that. It turns out there are a lot of possibilities in Manhattan (as opposed to the small town I grew up in...)

I snapped this one in March of 2013. In keeping with the theme of "famous buildings" the one that's on the very left of the photo is the Empire State Building. Just not the top portion that's instantly recognizable.

Canon EOS 400D 100-300mm @ 100mm 1/320, f/8

---

#### [2 May 2022: Claustrophobic](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/129094/)

**Coal Chute** – [LightBender](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/68136/)

[image: Coal Chute]

Fashion shoot at an old coal chute down by the quarry in Knoxville, TN some time in late 2011 or early 2012.

Nikon gear, Ilford film, settings unknown.

---

#### [25 April 2022: Claustrophobic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/129113/)

**Squeezing through 'Spooky Canyon'** – [Aganju](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/46784)

[image: Squeezing through 'Spooky Canyon']

Grand Staircase Escalante, Utah
iPhone 6s, ISO 160, 29mm, f 2.2, 1/30s

---

#### [18 April 2022: Famous Buildings](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128982/)

**St. Peter's Basilica** – [mfeldbauer](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/101511/)

[image: St. Peter's Basilica]

iPhone X, 28 mm, f1.8, ISO 25, 1/3003s

St. Peter's Basilica in the Vatican as seen through a window in Castel Sant'angelo in Rome. May 2019

---

#### [11 April 2022: Famous Buildings](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128979/)

**Statue of Liberty at Winter Dusk** – [Kevin Rubin](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/11891/)

[image: Statue of Liberty at Winter Dusk]

The Statue of Liberty near dusk on a February afternoon in 2013, as seen through some fencing near the Staten Island Ferry terminal.

Canon EOS 400D 100-300mm zoom @ 250mm 1/500, f/10

---

#### [4 April 2022: Freezing or Melting](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128894/)

**Blades of grass** – [spikey_richie](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/94572/)

[image: Blades of grass]

Olympus E-M10 Mark III ƒ/2.8 1/400 60 mm ISO800

I had to get right down for this one. It was taken at around 10am on a cold January, here in the UK. No post, straight out of the camera.

---

#### [28 March 2022: Freezing or Melting](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128853/)

**Frost flower** – [qrk](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/98537/)

[image: Frost flower]

Nikon D7000 & 18-140mm lens, 105mm, f/9, 1/160 s, ISO 200
3 Jan 2018

During a cold spell (a few degrees below freezing), the plant *Verbesinia virginica* (common name: Frostweed) in my backyard supported delicate frost flowers (water exuding from the split stem of the plant which freezes upon contact with the cold air) creating many interesting forms. This was a photographer's nightmare as there were hundreds of beautiful "flowers" to photograph.

---

#### [21 March 2022: Cross-section](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128748/)

**NZ Tree fern in cross section** - [MiguelH](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/60194/)

[image: NZ Tree fern in cross section]

Seen on Tiritiri Matangi, New Zealand

Panasonic Lumix GX80
f:4
ss:1/25th
51mm
ISO:1600

---

#### [14 March 2022: Cross-section](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128750/)

**Baguette** - [xenoid](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/75947/)

[image: Baguette]

Just finished lunch, remembered the contest, looked down on the table, ran to grab the camera. Hoping it makes you hungry.

Canon EOS 70D
Canon EF-S 35mm Macro
ISO 1250
f/9
1/60s
RawTherapee+Gimp.

Paris, 2022.03.01. CC-BY-SA

---

#### [7 March 2022: Death](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128672/)

**Dead flowers in a vase** - [dmkonlinux](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/60903/)

[image: Dead flowers in a vase]

Not been here for a while, but happened to be taking something appropriate to the theme last weekend (13/02/21).

Olympus E-30
Olympus Zuiko Digital ED 40-150mm F4.0-5.6
@ f/8.0, 1/160, 45mm, ISO 200
Yongnuo YN560IV & YN560III speedlights (though I think by this stage one of them had run out of battery charge).
Light tent with black 'velvet' backdrop.
Processed in darktable.

---

#### [28 February 2022: Death](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128664/)

**Horse & Sheep skull found during my Bhrigu Lake Trek in Himachal Pradesh state of India** - [Creative Learner](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/74260/)

[image: Horse & Sheep skull found during my Bhrigu Lake Trek in Himachal Pradesh state of India]

Captured Date: Aug 30, 2021
Phone Used: OnePlus 5T
Focal Length: 4.10mm
White balance: auto
Aperture: f/1.7
Exposure time: 1/2043
ISO: 250

---

#### [21 February 2022: Manipulations](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128507/11924)

**Cosmic Lily** - [BobT](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/11772/)

[image: Cosmic Lily]

Water lily, split, mirrored, with 'cosmic' egg added...
Lily photo taken at Chicago Botanic Garden
Edited in Photoshop, oil paint filter

---

#### [14 February 2022: Manipulations](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128489/11924)

**Manipulated Monument** - [LightBender](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/68136/)

[image: Manipulated Monument]

23 images, stacked and blended to remove dozens of tourists at the East Coast Memorial, Battery Park, Manhattan, New York. Not a single use of the clone tool to preserve the names on the memorial (original is nearly 8 times this resolution, little hard to read them scaled down like this.)

[Contact sheet of source images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vLPt.jpg)

---

#### [7 February 2022: Wood](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128334/)

**Raindrops on planks** - [l0b0](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/3669/)

[image: Raindrops on planks]

Canon 7D, EF70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM, ƒ/2.8, 1/2500s, ISO 640
[Original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/41204532142/)

---

#### [31 January 2022: Wood](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128326/)

**out of the woods** - [MiguelH](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/60194/)

[image: out of the woods]

Wicksteed park. Kettering. Uk
Pixel 3a

---

#### [24 January 2022: Environmental Destruction](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128221/)

**Plastic Life** - [techolic](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/35330/)

[image: Plastic Life]

09/09/2017, Shanghai

EOS 6D, EF50 f/1.8 II, f/2, 1/400, ISO100

---

#### [17 January 2022: Environmental Destruction](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128221/)

**Road to destruction** - [MiguelH](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/60194/)

[image: Road to destruction]

Panasonic Lumix GX80
f:8, SS:1/320th, 42mm, ISO:200

Demolition a bridge over the A50 near Uttoxeter, UK. Replacement Bridge and new roads to follow....

---

#### [10 January 2022: Shot with Film](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128118/)

**Birthday Morning** – [rl4215](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/102930/)

[image: Birthday Morning]

I normally don't get up early, but thought I would try my luck on my birthday. Queen's Park, London (2021)

Kodak Ultramax 400, Pentax P30, 50mm f/1.7

---

#### [3 January 2022: Shot with Film](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/128046/)

**Flower Stem, Studio** – [BobT](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/11772/)

[image: Flower Stem, Studio]

Flower Stem, studio strobe/softbox
Shen-Hao 4x5, Nikkor 120mm Macro 1/125 f/16, Tri-X Pan, ISO 320
Epson 4870 scanner

Comment: It's great to see these photos.  They're a great source of inspiration into what can be captured and shown.

Comment: I haven't been back to photography much recently, *except* to come and check on the hall of fame. I'm sure I've said it before, but every time I'm blown away by the quality and diversity and downright awesomeness of your weekly photos!

Comment: That long exposure one is inspiring. Amazing talent here!