# Always get a form submission error editing hall of fame on first click

Tags: bug

For some reason, which I suspect is related to the huge volume of edits to the [Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) question, when I click the save I get a red error popup by the button. If I wait a second or two and try again, it works.

Not a big issue, since it ultimately saves, but I figured I'd post it.