# Photo of the Week is stuck

Tags: discussion

The 'Photo of the Week' is stuck on the below, and has been since I joined this Stack some 6+ months ago.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried submitting a picture to replace it?

Comment: No, I assumed there was a queue.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I changed the PotW to the most recent photo contest 2nd-place submission. I'll start cycling through other high-voted submissions.

Comment: I clicked on "Submit your photo" and was taken to the [image of the week "Hall of fame"](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)(quotes in the original).  I didn't see where to submit a photo.

Comment: yeah, we don't really have a submission place yet. And I'm unable to update the PotW without providing a URL to a Meta page. Bear with us.... thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much *stuck*, as it is the fact that we don't have a current photo contest going.

We had a Photo of the Week Contest going for nearly a decade, but it suffered from having too deep of a submission queue (where substantially older submissions had higher votes than newer submissions), as well as low current participation.

Additionally, several community members who would otherwise normally submit contributions don't, because of Stack Exchange's CC BY-SA licensing policy.

Some of us had attempted to restart a new photo monthly photo contest, but it withered on the vine, partly due to reasons similar to those I mentioned, partly due to overcome by events, and partly just due to "2020".

Comment: So should the feature be removed?

Comment: I don't know the practicality of it - but would you see support to just recycle all the old winners (or even interspersed with the current queue) just for some variety? I (or anyone) could raise this as a new meta if the idea isn't too impractical.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's an interesting idea. How about cycling through the 2nd-highest votes of the last few contests over on main?

Comment: Sure - anything like that, just to get it cycling round again for a bit of interest. I was mainly worried at how much admin effort it is to shuffle them all round each time.